# Apostrophe (Smart Quote) in search throws Apache 400 Bad Request

Tags: html, apache, url, apostrophe

I have a search form in my web application that throws an Apache 400 Bad Request error when you search using an apostrophe (smart quote, i.e. **`’`** not **`'`**). This happens when someone copy and pastes from Microsoft Word (which automatically converts tick marks to smart quotes).

[image: search box]

The form causes a GET request which puts the search string in the URL. Even when I encode the string, it causes this error. What should I do to get this to work?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function zend_submit_main() {

    var query = $('#search_field').val();

    if(query != '') {
        var search_field = '/query/' + escape(query);
        var url = '/search/results' + search_field + '/active-tab/contacts';
        window.location = url;
    }

    return false;
}

</script>

<form id="search_form" method="GET" onsubmit="zend_submit_main(); return false;">
    <input type="text" value="search by contact name" onFocus="if (this.value=='search by contact name') { this.value=''; }" onBlur="if (this.value=='') { this.value='search by contact name'; }" name="search_field" id="search_field" style="width:160px;" />
    <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) instead of `escape`:

```
var search_field = '/query/' + encodeURIComponent(query);
```

`escape` is not a standard function and does not encode the value according to the [Percent-encoding as specified by RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.1). `’` for example is encoded as `"%u2019`.

Comment: Is this a case of *great minds answer alike?* I was *just* about to add the link to the *same page* :P

Comment: @Pekka: Zwei Dumme, ein Gedanke. ;)

Comment: ahahaha! Also a valid interpretation :)